# What are these 3 warning icons in my Toyota Vios that suddenly appeared after I parked and stopped the engine for a while then tried to re-start

Tags: toyota

While I was driving I felt that it was a bit heavy, but I doubt I had my clutch on. I was driving all the way home and it just failed as soon as I got home and opened the gates and tried to re-start my engine. These icons simultaneously for the first time.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the oil level recently? When was it last serviced?

Comment: Will do so tomorrow it's raining too hard and parked outside. Probably a year ago

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would expect those icons if an engine were to die suddenly. You'd also see them when you turn the key to the "on" position just before starting the engine. Have you had the codes read? I'm sure this would point you in the direction of what's actually going on.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It just died a few moments ago. I don't have the tools to read codes that you plug in the car dashboard so I might have to ask someone to do it from a repair shop. Thanks

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 My dad just changed the car battery and it worked :)

Comment: If the battery died, you need to see if there is an underlying cause for it to have died, like: Is the alternator working? If you don't, you could end up where you were at in the first place. A dead battery doesn't usually cause the engine to stop running unless the alternator stops putting out juice in the first place.

Comment: My father checked the battery it was at 12V before starting. Went down to 11V after starting of engine. Then went up to 13V during running of the car. He says the alternator should be working because there is an increase in voltage. Oil levels are ok, the ATF levels are ok. Brake fluids are ok. The engine didn't stop running while I was on the go but when I parked my car to open the gate and shut off my engine, I couldn't get it to start again